# Wordwrapping php-> javascript

Tags: javascript, php, document.write

I have this text in my mysql-database:

> Hi
>   how are you?

Working (php):

```
echo $row['text'];
```

Now working:

```
<script>
test = "<?php echo $comment; ?>";
document.writeln(test.parseURL().parseUsername().parseHashtag());
</script>
```

The error is nothing printed.

The javascript function:

```
 <script>
String.prototype.parseURL = function() {
return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&~\?\/.=]+/g, function(url) {
return url.link(url);
});
};

String.prototype.parseUsername = function() {
return this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(u) {
    var username = u.replace("@","")
    return u.link("http://url.com/"+username);
});
};

String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Ö–a-ö0-9-_]+/g, function(t) {
    var tag = t.replace("#","")
    return t.link("/?p=tagga&q="+tag);
});
};
</script>
```

But if I have it without the line break so it works
Hi! How are you?

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Always look at the rendered output. In this case:

```
test = "Hi
how are you?";
```

This is clearly invalid (unterminated string constant).

When dumping PHP variables into JS, ALWAYS use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode).

```
test = <?=json_encode($row['text'])?>;
```

Output:

```
test = "Hi\nhow are you?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript literal multiline strings are nothing like multiline line strings in PHP. Either escape the newline e.g.

```
var text = 'Hi \
how are you?'
```

Or make it one single line e.g.

```
var text = 'Hi\nHow are you?';
```

Comment: To save in database:
$ text = mysql_real_escape_string ($ _POST ['tag']);

What code should I use instead?

Comment: Saving is not the problem. It's the ouput. You will need to make sure it's proper javascript.